# Add label to slider in Matlab ui figure

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm trying to extend the example given [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/374973-update-plot-based-on-two-sliders) for a linear plot with two sliders that adjust the slope and y-intercept. I am adding a few more sliders, so now they need labels. However, I haven't been able to find anything concerning a slide label in the Matlab documentation. I tried to just add text with the `text()` function one would normally use for a plot, but the only place where that works is actually inside the plot, and not next to a slider. How would I do this?

Comment: Add a `uicontrol` with the `text` style

Comment: @David ah, I had not realized that was a possibility. It's well hidden in their documentation. Thanks!